# Can't open a device node after setenforce 0

Tags: java, android, android-source, selinux, seandroid

im trying to get some data from a device file at path `/dev/graphics/fb0` in service, U have root permission and execute the `chmod 777` command, then I got an "permission denied" error.
Then I excuted: `setenforce 0`, and the error disappears, but the file's size is still zero

```
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/dev/graphics/fb0", "rw");
        FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
        logText.setText(raf.length() + " "); // length is 0
        MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.PRIVATE, 0, 1024 * 1920 * 4);
        raf.close();

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/dev/graphics/fb0");
        logText.setText(fileInputStream.available() + " "); // available is still 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't supposed to do normal *read* on framebuffer AFAIK.

You'll need to use `ioctl` sys call to read/write into it. See some examples:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/donut-release/tests/framebuffer/fb_test.c

http://betteros.org/tut/graphics1.php

Comment: Thank You for sharing these urls,I have read them and got the data in JNI